# Make MySQL use mutliple cores for one query

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL-Query which lasts for about 50 seconds using only 1 core.

After verify why it takes so long i checked htop and iotop which leads to the result that the CPU is the bottleneck.

Is it possible to MySQL run a single query with all available CPU cores?

Comment: I'd first like to see the query and whether or not you have tuned it using, e.g., an index.  You can always add more cores but if you can improve the base query first you should do that.

Comment: possible relevant question over @ dba: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-than-one-core

Comment: Show [Explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) output of query.

Comment: https://imageshack.com/i/pmPBUQJHp

Comment: Here is the query and explain result